# SQL command returning 0 rows in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I don't know how to explain this.  I run my command in adminer and it returns the one row I have stored.  But when I run the command in my php portion it returns 0 rows.

```
function loadSettings() {
    global $mysqli;

    $settingsQuery = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM settings");
    $settingsQuery->execute();


    $settingsQuery->bind_result($tD, $tW, $tAs, $tA);
    echo "$settingsQuery->num_rows"; // Nothing here, variables are blank.
}
```

Comment: You have an extra **$** on tD

Comment: Remove the quotes from the echo statement

Comment: As for the $ that was an accident when I posted it here, I was renaming things when I posted here.  Not in a good mood and then I ran into this issue.  As for the echo, it echos out "0" so removing quotes won't do anything.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php#71988

Answer (score 0):

Added a store_result and fetch inline with the execute/bind_result and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please make some changes in your loadSettings() function like this:

global $mysqli;

```
$settingsQuery = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM settings");
$settingsQuery->execute();

$settingsQuery->bind_result($tD, $tW, $tAs, $tA);
$settingsQuery->store_result(); //store_result() "binds" the last given answer to the statement-object for... reasons. Now we can use it!
echo "$settingsQuery->num_rows"; // Nothing here, variables are blank.
```

Hope it helps. All the Best!